# KeyedCollection String Case Insensitive

Tags: .net, string-comparison, iequalitycomparer

Tried following the documentation and I cannot make it work.  Have a KeyedCollection with the key string.

How to make the string key case insensitive in a KeyedCollection?

On a Dictionary can just pass  StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase in the ctor.

```
private static WordDefKeyed wordDefKeyed = new WordDefKeyed(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);   // this fails

public class WordDefKeyed : KeyedCollection<string, WordDef>
{
        // The parameterless constructor of the base class creates a 
        // KeyedCollection with an internal dictionary. For this code 
        // example, no other constructors are exposed.
        //
        public WordDefKeyed() : base() { }

        public WordDefKeyed(IEqualityComparer<string> comparer)
            : base(comparer)
        {
            // what do I do here???????
        }

        // This is the only method that absolutely must be overridden,
        // because without it the KeyedCollection cannot extract the
        // keys from the items. The input parameter type is the 
        // second generic type argument, in this case OrderItem, and 
        // the return value type is the first generic type argument,
        // in this case int.
        //
        protected override string GetKeyForItem(WordDef item)
        {
            // In this example, the key is the part number.
            return item.Word;
        }
}

private static Dictionary<string, int> stemDef = new Dictionary<string, int(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);   // this works this is what I want for KeyedCollection
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want your type `WordDefKeyed` to be case-insensitive by default, then your default, parameterless constructor should pass an [`IEqualityComparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) instance to it, like so:

```
public WordDefKeyed() : base(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) { }
```

The [`StringComparer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx) has some default `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementations that are commonly used depending on the type of data you are storing:

- [`StringComparer.Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal) and [`StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase.aspx) - Used when you're using machine-readable strings, not strings that are entered or displayed to the user.
- [`StringComparer.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantculture) and [`StringComparer.CultureInvariantIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase) - Used when you're using strings that won't be shown to the UI, but are sensitive to culture and may be the same across cultures.
- [`StringComparer.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentculture) and [`StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.currentcultureignorecase) - Use for strings that are specific to the current culture, such as when you're gathering user input.

If you need a `StringComparer` for a culture *other* than the one that is the current culture, then you can call the static [`Create` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.create.aspx) to create a `StringComparer` for a specific [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx).